# Nhibernate Update timestamp

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

Is there a way to do
"UPDATE Item SET start_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" ?
in Nhibernate without using hql/sql.

I am trying to avoid hql/sql because the rest of my code is in criteria. I want to do something like :

```
var item = session.get<Item>(id)
item.start_date = current_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways and sql is correct one.

Either you will

1. load all entities, change, update and commit, or
2. write sql query and let dbms handle most of the work

Comment: I am trying to avoid hql/sql because the rest of my code is in criteria.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to avoid hql/sql because the rest of my code is in criteria

That is not a valid argument. Criteria is an API intended for relational search, and it does not support mass updates.

Different tasks, different APIs.

In this case, you can use either HQL or SQL, as the syntax is the same. I recommend the former, because you'll be using your entity/property names instead of table/column ones.